# Failed when trying out in publisher portal

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Environment details:

1. wso2am-4.0.0
2. new keystore with self-signed certificate "my.domain.somewhere.com"
3. I follow [this doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/#creating-a-keystore-using-a-new-certificate) to create newstore.

When test from tryout page in publisher portal , fails response:

```
{
      "code": "900901",
      "message": "Invalid Credentials",
      "description": "Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
    }
```

in devportal , tryout is ok.

the error in console :

```
TID: [-1] [] [2022-03-16 15:30:11,365]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
TID: [-1] [] [2022-03-16 15:31:03,204]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-03-16 15:31:03,333] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.authenticator.InternalAPIKeyAuthenticator} - Invalid Internal Key. Signature verification failed.
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-03-16 15:31:03,333]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} - API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Publisher tryout key validation, WSO2 uses the `gateway_certificate_alias` in the client-truststore. So you need to update that also with the public key of your new cert.